# Electromagnetic induction metal detection circuit

Tags: coil, induction, detector, metal, proximity

I am trying to develop a metal detector for use in a minesweeper competition. I aim to use a coil based metal detector because it has a long range and can detect underground metals.

There was a popular circuit online, but it used the obsolete TDA0161 IC from STMicroelectronics.

I have been searching for new ICs that can be used to make a metal detector. I found interesting ICs from STM microelectronics: [LDC1612](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ldc1614.pdf?ts=1664462137289&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLDC1614)

I have been scrolling the datasheet and I found that it has several LC ports. To my knowledge I think it may work, but I wanted to ask first to make sure that I am not making a wrong approach or if there is something that I do not know due to my lack of experience.

I am wondering if it's possible to create a metal detector using this IC, and if there are better ICs that are not obselete out there. Will it be able to support long ranges if I use a large enough coil?

Comment: have you done research about using LDC1612 for a metal detector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am wondering if it's possible to create a metal detector using this
> IC*

You are putting the cart before the horses I'm afraid to say. Concentrate on figuring out the operating frequency required and how much flux density it needs to produce. This in turn will likely force you into abandoning the chip you mention. I've designed a couple of industrial metal detectors in the past so, you can rely on what I'm saying.

Next, you have to design the receiver coil(s) and, the likely best option for you is called an inductive balance. Then you need to decide how you discriminate between wanted metal and unwanted trash aka ground effect.

All of these things push you further away from the chip you mention in my opinion. Don't get me wrong, I've looked at that chip several times in the past decade or so but, I have similarly concluded that it offers nothing for a metal detector of the type you want to build.

> *if there are better ICs that are not obsolete out there*

Don't fixate on the chip; there isn't a single chip solution here. For a start the oscillator will still probably be best designed with transistors in an oscillator.

The receiver front-end can now be op-amps (not so when I first designed my metal detectors). So, realistically, the main chips in the receiver chain will be op-amps.

> *Will it be able to support long ranges if I use a large enough coil?*

I've had my designs used in metal detectors that you could push a tree through. The good side is that inductance is bigger but, the current is smaller and, if the current is smaller you get less magnetic field. So, it's swings and roundabouts. A bigger coil certainly gets you more depth of penetration but it's no-way a linear relationship and doubling the coil area probably only gets you 20% more depth penetration.

So, concentrate on the important things as mentioned above and forget about trying to hang the more important things around a chip that will be fairly useless in the type of application you appear to be suggesting.

Creating resonance in the coils (inductive balance type) is absolutely paramount for increasing the magnetic field by nearly an order of magnitude. You need to create something in the order of 5 or ten amps (or ampere turns) to get anything like a moderate design. This resonant coil (the search head coil) can only be driven by transistors so, it makes sense to use a transistor oscillator that oscillates at the resonant point of the coil and resonating capacitors (proper capacitors that can handle the current).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort in posting this amazing answer.